# How to get the phone language with libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm tyring to set a default language for my game and I would like it to be the phone's language, the question is: how can I get the phone's language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my last game I used the default locale of the JVM:

```
java.util.Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

to get the device language. That seemed to work fine for Android as well.

Comment: Awesome dude, I didn't think about using Locale, I don't know why! I'll accept once I can.

Comment: Beware, on iOS if you set your language to English it will still return the phone's native set language. To confirm, doesn't work in iOS.