# Libgdx multiple language assets

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a game with libgdx where all game text is bitmap images. I want to use different asset images for different languages. For android you can put your assets under the res directory in the right locale code folder. but apparently there is no way to do something similar in libgdx.

Libgdx have some sort of managing strings but not game assets as i have found in the doc [I18n & L10n](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization).

After some digging I have found this class [PrefixFileHandleResolver](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/PrefixFileHandleResolver.java) but I'm not quite sure if it is the right option or how to properly use it.

Any ideas? thanks in advance :D

Comment: I probably borked your most recent edit. Notice how the HTTP reference goes at the very bottom of your post. The `[1]:` should start a new line and there should be no space after it. Feel free to fix the rest as you see fit.

Comment: I'll try to fix it thank you :D

Comment: As I am soon want to localize to Korean this I would like to see an answer. I have done little research but was wondering this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FileHandleResolver` as you thought. Just implement your own one by overriding

```
    @Override
    public FileHandle resolve(String fileName)
    {
        fileName = yourLogicToFindYourLanguageFile(fileName);
        return Gdx.files.internal(fileName);
    }
```

Easiest use is with an `AssetManager` (which I would recommend you to use anyway) - just pass your own `FileHandleResolver` in `AssetManager`'s constructor.

Comment: thank you very much :D. I have i have tried  `filename = filename + java.util.Locale.getDefault().toString();` and it works fine for me but it doesn't seem to work fine for ios when you change the language as mentioned in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888154/how-to-get-the-phone-language-with-libgdx) .